# Preventing connections from illegitimate clients

Tags: java, security

I've got a client/server setup in Java. The client currently transmits a calculated value to the server (via socket, in addition to login/password) in order to authenticate.

However, there is currently nothing preventing a maliciously decompiled and refactored client from connecting, because all it would need to do is send the same authentication data.

Given that decompilation reveals everything my client is doing, is there really any way to *reasonably* prevent connections from modified clients? It seems to me that the only way to accomplish this is to generate a unique token that a modified client (with identical token-generation logic) would, somehow, be incapable of generating.

Comment: Rule #1 of the SO club: Never trust the clients

Comment: *"all it would need to do is send the same authentication data"* -- but how would it know the username and password? Or are those hardcoded in the client software too?

Comment: @Arjan It is free to register an account, so usernames and passwords are not strictly controlled/issued

Comment: You describe *Message Authentication Code*.

Comment: But, @Marcus, how would one hide the MAC's secret key in the application?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really avoid fake clients (look at how proprietary softwares/protocols get reverse-engineered), but that's no problem because you should **never** trust the client: check every request he makes so that he cannot cause problems. If you do so, even a fake client will have to respect your rules and will not be a problem at all.

Anyway, another way is to make the protocol you use obfuscated so it cannot be easily decompiled and the protocol cannot be reverse-engineered, but you would be amazed by the ability of certain people to break what you do anyway. Making your code obscure is rarely a benefit and makes you loose time most of the time.

Comment: Ideally yes, but there are so many possible command/behaviour interactions that policing ALL requests server-side would be much more time consuming than an obfuscatory effort. Currently only the most critical and obvious behaviours are interrogated for legitimacy

Comment: I do not know what kind of server you want to develop, but usually it is not a problem